# PendingDeprecationWarning: cgi.parse_qsl is deprecated, use urlparse.parse_qsl instead

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, urlparse

warning message:

```
File "procesador.py", line 10, in <module>
    from model import *
  File "/Users/juque/Proyectos/est/patan/_patan/model.py", line 14, in <module>
    b_engine = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/intranet?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0', pool_recycle=3600, echo=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.1dev-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 263, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.1dev-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 48, in create
    u = url.make_url(name_or_url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.1dev-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 171, in make_url
    return _parse_rfc1738_args(name_or_url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.1dev-py2.7-macosx-10.5-fat3.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 196, in _parse_rfc1738_args
    query = (len(tokens) > 1 and dict(cgi.parse_qsl(tokens[1]))) or None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 191, in parse_qsl
    PendingDeprecationWarning, 2)
PendingDeprecationWarning: cgi.parse_qsl is deprecated, use urlparse.parse_qsl instead
```

Well, the warning is very clear, but *i don't know why* this happend if supposed I'm using the last version of SQLAlchemy (0.7, stable and dev) and python 2.7.

Or is this a Bug?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/intro.html#supported-platforms):

> ### Supported Platforms
>
> SQLAlchemy has been tested against the following platforms:
>
> - cPython since version 2.4, through the 2.xx series
> - cPython version 3, throughout all 3.xx series
> - Jython 2.5 or greater
> - Pypy 1.5 or greater

Not all of those *have* `urlparse.parse_qsl()`. If you feel that this is a problem then you should complain to the SQLAlchemy developers.